# Add keyfile to existing Mongo ReplicaSet

Tags: mongodb, authentication, replication

I am trying to add authentication to an existing live Mongo 2.4.3 instance with 3 nodes. I generated a keyfile that is owned by mongodb with 400 permissions. This file is copied to the same location on all 3 servers. I am trying to add the keyfile without the clients noticing that mongo is going down. The priorities of the instances are set to 3, 1, & 0, which I will refer to n1, n2, & n3

Here is what I tried so far:

1. I restarted both n2 & n3 with the keyfile. n1 turned itself into a secondary and n2 & n3 did not reconnect to the replicaset

   I shut down both n2 & n3 and restarted n1 with the keyfile. After n1 came up as a secondary in the set, I then restarted n3 with the keyfile to allow an election with a majority of the members. Then n1 & n3 seemed to come out of the replicaset. I got this message on n1: [not electing self, n3 would veto with 'I don't think n1 is electable']

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "Then n1 & n3 seemed to come out of the replicaset" ?  
For election purposes, you should try to have odd no of nodes for doing election. Tying adding n2 also, then it should work

Comment: how can the clients not notice when they now will need to start authenticating to the replica set?

Comment: replica set nodes with keyfile can't talk to other nodes without the keyfile.  What happened after n1 didn't elect itself?  Did n1 and n3 wait a few seconds and then elected n1?

Comment: @AbhishekKumar, It all cases I had an odd number of members in my set. It just happened to be the case that one of them was unavailable but they should be able to elect themselves nonetheless.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky, after I added n3 to have a necessary quorum to elect a primary, n1 kept saying in its logs that it would not elect itself because n3 would veto.

Comment: Since diagnosing what happened would be beyond the scope of this forum (just straight-forward Q&As here, I recommend posting this question (with appropriate snippets from log files) on mongodb-users google group.